# email sender with grails mail plugin

Tags: email, grails, plugins, sender

im trying to send email with mail plugin in grails with the gmail account.
The email is sent successfully but i have a problem with the sender of the email

In Config.groovy

```
grails {
 mail {
 host = "smtp.gmail.com"
 port = 465
 username = "myacount@gmail.com"
 password = "mypassword"
 props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",                     
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
          "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]

 } 
}
```

Then from my app, i call

```
mailService.sendMail {
            to "another@gmail.com"
            from "sender@gmail.com"
            subject sub
            body message
        }
```

The email is sent fine to another@gmail.com, but  the sender is not the sender@gmail.com but the myaccount@gmail.com. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this in on GMail. It forces you to use the "myaccount@gmail.com", you'll need to either use a local provide, another provider all together or accept "myaccount@gmail.com".

I believe this is done on purpose to prevent people from sending spam through Gmail.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a way to change the 'from' under certain conditions, see http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct answer to the question, in case anyone else lands here looking for a way to send a human readable sender address, you can do so by specifying it as such

from: "Sender Name"